# how to fix my page from becoming wider using js and css for a parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like I was saying for some reason my screen ends up becoming wider when I scroll. My goal is to be able to click the about me section and it scrolls to the about me section or div. when I do this, however, I see that it is making the sections wider. What is making the section wider is the actual js but I don't know why.

html file

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <img class="my-pic" src="./images/me.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <ul class="the-links">
        <li class="links" id="about-me">About Me</li>
        <li class="links" id="my-projects">My Projects</li>
        <li class="links" id="contact-me">Contact Me</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="me">
        <h1>About Me Section</h1>
        <br />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet at
          ad tenetur omnis perferendis totam id praesentium ab eius harum,
          asperiores consequuntur nemo iste, consectetur earum porro rem
          quisquam sapiente veritatis voluptatem non quae reprehenderit? Iste
          rerum necessitatibus harum aut autem totam incidunt eaque a, excepturi
          culpa, error blanditiis quaerat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="projects">My Projects Section</div>
      <div class="contact">Contact Me Section</div>
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css file

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(156, 120, 240), rgb(169, 140, 194));
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.my-pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 8%;
  transform: translate(-8%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.links {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  list-style: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: "Style Script", cursive;
  padding: 10px;
}

.links:hover {
  background: rgb(41, 3, 58);
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: "Style Script", cursive;
  padding: 10px;
}

#about-me {
  left: 60%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -30%);
  position: absolute;
}

#my-projects {
  left: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

#contact-me {
  left: 60%;
  top: 70%;
  transform: translate(-60%, -70%);
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  z-index: 0;
}

.me {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, black 20%, rgb(248, 28, 248));
}

.projects {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgb(8, 77, 23) 20%, rgb(248, 28, 248));
}

.contact {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: black;
}
```

js file

```js
const top_of_div =
  window.scrollY + document.querySelector(".me").getBoundingClientRect().top;
const scrollToMe = document.querySelector("ul");

console.log(top_of_div);

scrollToMe.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
  const target_id = e.target.id;
  if(target_id === 'about-me'){
    window.scroll({
        top: 1000,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
  }
});

function parallax(element, distance, speed) {
  const item = document.querySelector(element);

  item.style.transform = `translateY(${distance * speed}px)`;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  parallax(".header", window.scrollY, 0.8);
  parallax(".me", window.scrollY, 0.5);
  parallax(".projects", window.scrollY, 0.5);
  parallax(".contact", window.scrollY, 0.5);
});
```